# React.js does not differentiate between two components of same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure if this is a React.js bug or a "feature" of the Javascript language. I've got a React.js (*edit: using v0.12.x*) component called `Page` that acts as a router and selects child components based on the route. I created a mixin that adds a function called `runRoute` which takes a JSX component and uses `Page`'s `setState` method to update `state.routeComponent`. Additionally, `runRoute` also calls `forceUpdate()` to ensure that `Page` is re-rendered.

**The problem** is that it appears React does not differentiate two components in state when they are of the same class. I'll explain.

I have two sub-components called `Board` and `Profile`. `Board` is re-used for different contexts. If two consecutive routes are run that both use `<Board/>`, React.js does not update the UI. It's only when a consecutive route using a different class, such as `<Profile/>`, does the UI actually update. And if state changes to another route that uses `<Board/>` differently will it only update the UI to the appropriate state of `<Board/>`.

Here's some sample code below of `<Page/>` and my `Router` mixin:

**Router.js**

```
module.exports = function(){
  return {

    getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        routeComponent: null
      };
    },

    runRoute: function(component){
      this.setState({routeComponent: component});
      this.forceUpdate();
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.router = Router(self.routes).configure({
        resource: self, 
        notFound: self.notFound
      });
      self.router.init(); 
    }
  };
}
```

**Page.jsx**

```
module.exports = function(React, Router, NotFound, Profile, Board) {
  return React.createClass({

    mixins: [Router],

    routes: {
      '/board': 'trending',
      '/board/mostloved': 'mostLoved',
      '/profile': 'profile'
    },

    trending: function() {
      this.runRoute(
        <Board title="Trending Boards" setTitle={this.props.setTitle} />
      );
    },

    mostLoved: function() {
      this.runRoute(
        <Board title="Loved Boards" setTitle={this.props.setTitle} />
      );
    },

    profile: function() {
      this.runRoute(
        <Profile setTitle={this.props.setTitle} />
      );
    },

    notFound: function () {
      this.runRoute(
        <NotFound setTitle={this.props.setTitle} />
      );
    },

    render: function() {
      return this.state.routeComponent;
    }

  });
};
```

Appreciate if anyone has some insight into this. Thanks!

Comment: this might sound silly, but you have `Router.js` returning a function that's supposed to be called using the consuming component's state? Should `Page.jsx` be doing `mixins: [Router.call(this)],`? aren't mixins supposed to be regular objects whose methods are auto-bound to component state?

Comment: Doesn't sound silly, I think that's a good consideration. I read through this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins and call me silly but I wasn't able to gather that from the docs, so you might be on to something.

Comment: Just an update I got this working by wrapping each `<Board/>` component in it's own individual parent component. Not a great solution but it worked. I'll write an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't say for certain without looking at your `Board` component, but it looks like the problem is that its state depends on properties and you don't keep them in sync when properties are updated (after `runRoute`).

Here is simple example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/5012/)) that demonstrates the issue:

```
var Board = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {title: this.props.title}
  },
  render: function() {
    return <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
  }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {routeComponent: null}
  },

  handleClick: function(title) {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
      self.setState({ routeComponent: <Board title={title} /> })
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <a href='#' onClick={this.handleClick('Trending')}>Trending</a>
      <br/>
      <a href='#' onClick={this.handleClick('Most Loved')}>Most Loved</a>
      {this.state.routeComponent}
    </div>;
  }
});
```

Clicking on links changes state of the `Page` but does not change the visual representation of the `Board`.

You need to keep `Board`'s state in sync with it's updated properties by handling changes in [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops).

Just adding few lines to `Board` solves the problem:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(props) {
    this.setState({title: props.title})
  },
```

As a side note: you never need `this.forceUpdate()` immediately after `this.setState()`. If can't get required behavior without it, you doing something wrong.

Comment: Wow this actually looks like it will be a very big help. I'll be back testing this tomorrow so will update if necessary, but in the meantime I'm going to accept this as the answer since I was able to fix the issue in the jsFiddle you provided. Thank you.

Comment: A follow-up that it worked in our project. Additionally, I also found the methods `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` useful for related cases.